# "the fact that...." grammatical construction

Tags: grammar, complements

In the following sentence:

The issue is the fact that it is red.

What type of grammatical form is "that it is red"?

I think that it is some kind of noun clause that functions as an objective complement for "fact". Is there a term for this kind of clause? How might one diagram this kind of clause?

Comment: It's a relative clause modifying the noun "fact".

Comment: “The issue” cannot be “the fact that it is red”.
“The issue” might very well be *whether* “it is red” but that isn’t at all the same thing, is lt?